# How can i prevent form the user to move the point beyond the pictureBox1 borders?

Tags: c#

This is all the events and functions in my Form1 what should i do ?
I need to detect the borders/bounds of the pictureBox1 control and stop the mouse move when its touching the borders.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                label1.Text = e.X.ToString();
                label2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
                label1.Visible = true;
                label2.Visible = true;
                label3.Visible = true;
                label4.Visible = true;
                // find the index that is closest to the current mouse location
                MinDist = float.MaxValue;

                for (idx = 0; idx < Point_X.Count; ++idx)
                {
                    float dx = Point_X[idx] - e.X;
                    float dy = Point_Y[idx] - e.Y;
                    float dist = (float)Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

                    if (dist < MinDist)
                    {
                        MinDist = dist;
                        selectedIndex = idx;
                    }
                }



                if (MinDist < 5)
                {
                    mouseMove = true;
                    OriginalX = Point_X[(int)selectedIndex];
                    OriginalY = Point_Y[(int)selectedIndex];




                    if (cyclicSelectedIndex.Count() == 2)
                    {
                        cyclicSelectedIndex[currentCyclicIndex] = (int)selectedIndex;
                        currentCyclicIndex++;
                        if (currentCyclicIndex > 1)
                        {
                            currentCyclicIndex = 0;
                        }
                        if ((cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) || (cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == -1) || (cyclicSelectedIndex[1] == -1))
                        {
                            button2.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button2.Enabled = true;
                        }


                        label13.Text = selectedIndex.ToString();
                        label13.Visible = true;
                        label14.Visible = true;

                        listView1.Items.Add(selectedIndex.ToString()).EnsureVisible();
                    }

                }







            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseMove == true)
            {
                Point NewPoint = e.Location;
                Point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.X;
                Point_Y[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.Y;
                label1.Text = NewPoint.X.ToString();
                label2.Text = NewPoint.Y.ToString();
                pictureBox1.Refresh();

                Point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = Math.Max(pictureBox1.Left, Math.Min(pictureBox1.Right, NewPoint.X));

            }

        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseMove == true)
            {
                Point NewPoint = e.Location;
                Point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.X;
                Point_Y[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.Y;
                mouseMove = false;
            }

        }      

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            halfX = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width / 2;
            halfY = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height / 2;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            offsetX = rnd.Next(-10, 10);
            offsetY = rnd.Next(-10, 10);
            addPoint(halfX + offsetX, halfY + offsetY);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            numberOfPoints++;
            label16.Text = numberOfPoints.ToString();
            label16.Visible = true;
            label15.Visible = true;


        }

        private void addPoint(float x , float y)
        {
            Point_X.Add(x);
            Point_Y.Add(y);
            label5.Text = x.ToString();
            label6.Text = y.ToString();
            label5.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            label8.Visible = true;
        }

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
           Point connectionPointStart;
           Point connectionPointEnd;
           Graphics g = e.Graphics;
           g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
           SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
           Pen p = new Pen(brush);
               for (int idx = 0; idx < Point_X.Count; ++idx)
               {
                   Point dPoint = new Point((int)Point_X[idx], (int)Point_Y[idx]);
                   dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 5; // was - 2
                   dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 5; // was - 2
                   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(10, 10));
                   g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
               }

               for (int i = 0; i < connectionStart.Count; i++)
               {

                   int startIndex = connectionStart[i];
                   int endIndex = connectionEnd[i];



                   connectionPointStart = new Point((int)Point_X[startIndex], (int)Point_Y[startIndex]);
                   connectionPointEnd = new Point((int)Point_X[endIndex], (int)Point_Y[endIndex]);
                   p.Width = 4;
                   g.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);

               }


        }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addConnection(cyclicSelectedIndex[0], cyclicSelectedIndex[1]);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void addConnection(int i, int j)
        {

            if (cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == -1)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1])
            {
                return;
            }

            if (connectionStart.Count() == 0)
            {
                connectionStart.Add(i);
                connectionEnd.Add(j);
                //label12.Text = i.ToString();
                //label11.Text = j.ToString();
                label12.Text = connectionStart[0].ToString();
                label11.Text = connectionEnd[0].ToString();
                label9.Visible = true;
                label10.Visible = true;
                label11.Visible = true;
                label12.Visible = true;
                return;
            }

            for (int f = 0; f < connectionStart.Count(); f++)
            {
                if ((connectionStart[f] == i && connectionEnd[f] == j) || (connectionStart[f] == j && connectionEnd[f] == i)) // this checking dosent work good !
                {
                    button2.Enabled = false;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    label12.Text = connectionStart[f].ToString();
                    label11.Text = connectionEnd[f].ToString();
                    label9.Visible = true;
                    label10.Visible = true;
                    label11.Visible = true;
                    label12.Visible = true;
                }
            }

            connectionStart.Add(i);
            connectionEnd.Add(j);

        }
```

Im not sure how to explain it. But how can i do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When calculating the X value use `Math.Max` with that and the left boundary of the image, and `Min` on the right boundary of the image.  Do the same with the Y value on the Top and Bottom.

```
Point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = Math.Max(imageLeft, Math.Min(imageRight, NewPoint.X));
```

I assume you can determine the left/right/top/bottom of the image?

Comment: Servy my pictureBox1 is empty so i did for the first conditation:       Point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = Math.Max(pictureBox1.Left, Math.Min(pictureBox1.Right, NewPoint.X)); and what do i do with this calculation ? I added this line to the mouse move event.

Comment: What were you doing with it before you checked to ensure that it was inside of the picturebox?  This just ensures that the X,Y coords stay inside the picturebox.  Presumably you use them to set the location of your point.